# javascript compare int arrays and calculate difference for each

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops, foreach

I have 2 json files that get constantly modified. Their format is like this:

```
[ 
  { 
    "rank": 1,
    "points": 10 
  },
  { 
    "rank": 15,
    "points": 1601 
  }
]
```

so the amount of nested keys can be anything, in the example above there's 2.
I looped through the files and got the values I wanted from each nested key, and put them in an array.
so the array is like this `const array1 = [ "1", "15" ]` & `const array2 = [ "18", "5" ]` etc.
I now have 2 json files - arrays one showing the previous ranks (before modifying) and one showing the current ones.
What I am trying to do is, loop through the arrays and substract the ints between them, so then I can create a string that's like this: "Rank: 15 (-10)" (aka will indicate if it increased or decreased and how much. But since the array can be infinitely big , I have to create a loop that will substract array1[0] with array2[0] etc.

Don't know how, can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm a bit confused by this explanation; can you provide concrete input and output, the expected transformation, and [what you've tried so far](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0):

Kinda confused by your question... but I'll take a stab at it.  Seems as though you're just comparing the index position of one array to another, and providing some output.  Could do something like the following:

```
const arr1 = [1, 15, 43];
const arr2 = [18, 30, 12];

const compareRanks = (oldArray, newArray) => {
  oldArray.forEach((oldRank, index) => {
    const newRank = newArray[index];
    console.log(`Rank: ${newRank}(${oldRank - newRank})`);
  });
};

compareRanks(arr1, arr2);
```

It's worth noting this solution is fragile.  It requires both your arrays to be of equivalent size, as well as all elements are integers.  If you use this, it's best you build in some guard-rails to it otherwise it will throw an error if given incorrectly structured data.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you're case is given 2 arrays of integers, you want to the show the difference?

```js
/* given 2 arrays (of maybe non-equal length) */
const before = [10,20,30,40,50]
const after = [5,18,35,42,55,100]

/* derive the data needed */
const shorterArray = before.length <= after.length ? before : after
const pairs = shorterArray.map((ele, idx) => 
    ({
      points: ele,
      diff: ele - after[idx]
    })
  )
  
/* print output */
pairs.map(({points, diff}=x) =>             // use object destructuring to separate the elements
  console.log(`Rank: ${points} (${diff})`)) // print output
```